# Reactjs dynamic components loading factory

Tags: autoload, reactjs

I have a several reactjs components (let it would be a windows) in a separate files e.g.:

```
windows/window1.jsx
windows/window2.jsx
...
windows/windowN.jsx
```

I also have a component called "WindowManager" which I want to use for a quick invoking of the any window anywhere in the code.

Right now I should store all the possible windows inside WindowManager.jsx like this:

```
var windowsTypes = {
    window1        : require('windows/window1.jsx'),
    window2        : require('windows/window1.jsx'),
    ...
    windowN        : require('windows/windowN.jsx')
}
```

... and then call it like:

```
WindowManager.addWindow(windowTypes.windowN, { ... custom windowN-related props ...});
```

If I'll add a new window type then I should also add a new item "windowN": require(...) into "windowsTypes" list and it seems to me not very DRY solution. What I want to achieve is to get rid of neccesity of "windowsTypes".

Is there any clean way to do this? Probably with the help of additional plugins and libraries?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm using gulp + browserify + cssify + lint.

Comment: Probably I've found the answer: https://github.com/jsoverson/preprocess and https://github.com/bibliolabs/preprocessify
I will try and post the answer if it will work. But maybe it's not the only way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use your approach like this:

```
function addWindowExt(windowName, windowProps) // where windowName is string
{
    WindowManager.addWindow(require('windows/' + windowName + '.jsx'), windowProps);
}
```

Without the need of any pre filled map.

Comment: It works but it looks very ugly. If you'll need to change windowN.jsx location, you should find all the usages of the windowN and change them. It seems not very DRY.

Comment: If you are to change location of windowN.jsx you are in any case will have to go on through all its uses (IDE might help you with that though) and at least change imports that otherwise will be broken regardless of using this approach. And I do not really see how this breaks DRY principle.